# GuardDuty Configuration with Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-guardduty

How do you configure data sources with Cloudformation? For instance I want to add include tags in the malware data source which I can do from the UI

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ''
Resources:
  GuardDuty:
    Type: 'AWS::GuardDuty::Detector'
    Properties:
      Enable: true
      DataSources:
        Kubernetes:
          AuditLogs:
            Enable: false
        MalwareProtection:
          ScanEc2InstanceWithFindings:
            EbsVolumes: true            
        S3Logs:
          Enable: true
```